# How to write this notation?

Tags: math-mode

I found this notation when I read about split homomorphisms. How to write this notation?

[image]

Thank all!!!

Comment: Is this possibly Unicode 27F4, right arrow with circled plus?  (I don't know whether this is available directly with a font available for use with (La)TeX.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this for instance

```
$ M - \overset{f}{\oplus}  \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0 $
```

Answer (score 2):

For example I have used `accents` package to have the same output of the image. Here there are two alternatives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$M-\mkern-5mu\accentset{f}{\oplus}\to N\to 0;$

$M\mbox{---}\accentset{f}{\oplus}\to N\to 0;$
\end{document}
```

or, off-topic with the tag, using `tikz-cd` (or `xy`) package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}

\begin{document}
Sequence $\begin{tikzcd}
M -\!\overset{f}{\oplus}\! \to N \arrow[r] &[-1em] 0
\end{tikzcd}$ and stop.
\end{document}
```

[image]